# Help with Jordan form of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

I was studying Jordan descomposition of a Matrix, and I am really stuck in the algorithm to do this.

I start with the matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -3 & 1\\
1&5&-1\\
2&6&0
\end{pmatrix}.$$

I obtain the characteristic polynomial which is $-(x-2)^3,$ and then I find the eigenvectors, but when i try to make the canonical form, i can't find the correct generalized eigenvalue, because $(A-2I)x=v,$ with either $v$ eigenvector, has no solution.

I get the next eigenvectors: $v_1=(0,1,3),v_2=(1,0,1).$ Computing it online, the matrix $S$ (where $A=S J S^{-1}$), is different. The first column is the first $v_1$ but the second column is $v2-v1$ and this is where i get very confused.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: the minimal polynomial is $(x-2)^2.$  This means that the largest Jordan block is size 2. Then there is a singleton. So: find the actual eigenvectors, space of dimension 2. Then take any column vector $w$   such that $(A-2I)w \neq 0.$  Consitency comes from defining $v = (A-2I)w$  as one of the genuine eigenvectors. Then take a genuine eigenvector $u$  that is not a multiple of $v.$   Make the matrix $S$  have the columns $u,v,w.$  And calculate $S^{-1}$   followed by $J = S^{-1} A S$

Comment: the method above is pretty good when all matrix elements and eigenvalues are integers. The possible fractions come entirely from inverting $S$  which is all integers. But this is the (integer)  adjoint matrix divided by the determinant of $S;$  a single occurrence of $\frac{1}{\det S}.$